# Excel Online connection to Azure Analysis Services?

Tags: excel, azure-analysis-services, excel-online

Is it possible to connect to Azure Analysis Services from Excel Online?

I can't find any option to do it, like in the offline version (Data -> Get Data). If I create a file in Excel desktop version and open it online there is a Refresh button shown (Data -> Refresh Selected Connections). However, when I click it, it returns an error.

I can't seem to find any information on the Microsoft site about it.

Comment: From my experience I would suggest you create the connection in the desktop. Then upload your document to Onedrive and access online from there...?

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, you cannot connect Azure Analysis services from Excel Online.

**Reason:** The Online version of Excel is limited features - where get data is missing.

Appreciate if you could share the feedback on our [feedback channel](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/search/d92323a0-0525-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858?q=connect%20from%20excel%20online). Which would be open for the user community to upvote & comment on. This allows our product teams to effectively prioritize your request against our existing feature backlog and gives insight into the potential impact of implementing the suggested feature.