# Excel Online - Unable To Refresh and Manipulate a Power BI Data Source Based Off Azure Analysis Service Tabular Cube

Tags: excel, powerbi, pivot-table, powerbi-datasource, excel-online

I'm am basically trying to work around [this limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70258265/excel-online-connection-to-azure-analysis-services) by placing a Power BI dataset on top of a Azure Analysis Cube and accessing the data set through excel online.

I have a Azure Analysis Service instance with a single cube:

[image]

It builds fine, I can access it from excel on my desktop without issue.

I created a PowerBI report and associated dataset based on this cube, I can access this and refresh the PowerBI dataset from excel on my desktop without issue, works great:

[image]

However when I click the "Analyze In Excel" button and download a fully function file, if I upload that file to OneDrive(same user account) and attempt to open it in Excel Online I get the following error:

[image]

**Why? It work in my excel desktop version without issue?** I can see that the Pivot Table is supported in excel online(and it appears to me as though excel online support pivot table connections to "Power BI"):

[image]

[image]

### Update 1

I can actually see and add it through the button shown above, however when I do that I see:

[image]

I'm logged in as the user who created the PowerBI report and I'm a admin on the Azure Analysis Service instance.

### Update 2

I attempted this with a co-worker account, seems to work fine with his, so it must be related to some property of my Azure user account. I also found [this post](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Service/Error-connecting-to-XMLA-endpoints-from-Excel/m-p/2208579) which is the only one reporting the same error in excel online other than this post:

> Cannot create the PivotTable
>
> An error has occurred creating the PivotTable. Please make sure you
> have permissions to the data, the model is valid and the credentials
> are correct.

Stating that I need to:

- Allow Live Connections
- Allow XMLA endpoints and Analyze in Excel with on-premises datasets

Is that related to this?